# Convert Byte to Bitmap

Tags: java, android, byte

I have to convert a byte to Bitmap and i set it to imageview

i do have methode that convert Bitmap in ImageView into Byte and i insert it later,

```
public static byte[] ConvertDrawableToByteArray(Drawable drawableResource) {

             Bitmap imageBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawableResource).getBitmap();
            ByteArrayOutputStream imageByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, imageByteStream);
            byte[] imageByteData = imageByteStream.toByteArray();
            return imageByteData;

}
```

and when i want to retrieve image from database and show it in an ImageView i do

```
 //--
             byte[] image_b   = c.getBlob(4);
             Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image_b, 0, image_b.length);
             img.setImageBitmap(b);
```

but it return  nothing

what is wrong, please help

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with your debugger?

Comment: please post your stacktrace/logcat when you trying to getting the blob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's because the cursor didn't return anything. Maybe the Blob is too big to be queried in one time because android cursor limit is 1 mb per query please check again your stacktrace/logcat and if the blob size is the problem you can try to split the byte to smaller size and store it in your database

Comment: i have this in logcat  and i dont understan ` error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
 Skipped 101 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
Skipping entry 0x7f020002 in package table 0 because it is not complex!
 GREF has increased to 201
SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 GC_CONCURRENT freed 1814K, 7% free 26919K/28860K, paused 95ms+25ms, total 237ms WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 143ms
03-19 16:23:05.556: D/skia(948): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null`

Comment: Yes I think you failed to get the byte[], have you tried to log the image_b? you can do it by convert image_b.toString() to check if the image_b really have any data or not

Comment: i have to restart Eclipse and i will try to log the image_b  did i must just add image_b.toString();

Comment: Okay i do likee this :`String t =  image_b.toString();
            System.out.println("what it give me" +t);`  and i find in the logcat this line : `03-19 17:01:28.167: I/System.out(1019): what it give me[B@41f1f5c0`

Comment: ah I'm sorry I forgot that's an array of byte please log the length of the byte with image_b.length

Comment: Hi, thanks for replay , i do  `int t =  image_b.length;
            System.out.println("length is : " +t);` and  it show this in the Logcat  `length is : 9`

Comment: now try to log the imageByteData length and compare it, if the length is different that means somethings wrong with your cursor maybe as I said in my answer it's because the size is too big

Comment: I guess you have to split the Byte to some part and insert it to the database or instead of saving the byte you can save the path to your drawable it's more simpler and it'll consume less memory :)

Comment: Yes Good idea Thanks a lot,  it's fine now thanks to you @NAYOSO

Answer (score 0):

You can play around with the following and let us know if it works:

```
String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = resolver.query(imageUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand where is the problèlme i do likee this :String t = image_b.toString(); System.out.println("what it give me" +t); and i find in the logcat this line : 03-19 17:01:28.167: I/System.out(1019): what it give me[B@41f1f5c0

is that mean it return something but dont showin or is the byte `[B@41f1f5c0` is not correct